# Installing the AAB from Google Play keeps crashing but installing manually from APK works with no problems

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

When I export and upload the ABB file for the Google Play Store, the version that is downloaded just crashes and errors out, but when I export it as an APK the app works just fine.

I'm not sure why this has happened.

Comment: When an app crashes it provides a log in logcat. Please add logcat information to your question or no-one will be able to help you.